# Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ with range $[0,1]$. Show that there is some $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=1-c$

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ with range $[0,1]$. Show that there is some $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=1-c$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$f(c)=1-c$$
$$f(c)-1+c=0$$

$$g(c)=f(c)-1+c$$

$g(c)$ will be continuous function in $[0,1]$ as sum of two continuous functions will also be continuous.

If we can prove that there $g(c)$ will have atleast one root in $[0,1]$, then we are done.

$$g(0)=f(0)-1$$
$$g(0)\in [0,1]-1$$
$$g(0)\in[-1,0]\tag{1}$$

$$g(1)=f(1)-1+1$$
$$g(1)=f(1)$$
$$g(1)\in[0,1]\tag{2}$$

**Case $1$:** If $g(0)$ or $g(1)$ goes $0$, then we are done because then $g(c)$ will be having at least one root in $[0,1]$

**Case $2$:** If $g(0)$ is negative and $g(1)$ is positive, then what we can say?

By intermediate value theorem, we can say that as $g(0)<0<g(1)$, so there will exists some c in $(0,1)$ for which $g(c)$ is zero.

But I have a counter, what if $g(c)$ is like following:-

[image] 
Here we are getting no $c$ in $(0,1)$ for which $g(c)$ is zero.

Comment: Your picture does not even depict a function from some subset $U\subset\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ because negative numbers are mapped to two distinct numbers

Comment: That is not the graph of a function from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @MartinR, I have drawn the graph of $g(c)$ not $f(x)$. We don't know the domain and range of $g(c)$

Comment: Still, your "counterexample" is not a function. Your prove is fine though.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x)=1-f(x)-x$ Then $g$ is continuous and $g(0) \geq 0$, $g(1) \leq 0$. Hence there exists $c$ such that $g(c)=0$ which gives $f(c)=1-c$.

Comment: Interesting that your answer looks at the domain of f and mine looks at the range.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - (1-x)$.

There is an $x_0$
such that
$f(x_0) = 0$
and an $x_1$
such that
$f(x_1) = 1$.

$g(x_0)
=f(x_0) - (1-x_0)
=0 - (1-x_0)
=x_0-1
\le 0
$
and
$g(x_1)
=f(x_1) - (1-x_1)
=1 - (1-x_0)
=x_1
\ge 0
$.

Therefore,
since $g(x)$
is continuous,
there is an $x$ 
in $[\min(x_0, x_1), \max(x_0, x_1)]$
with $g(x) = 0$
so $f(x) = 1-x$.